# Manually triggering delete using Sketch Widget for ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the sketch widget for ArcGIS JavaScript: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html

There is a "delete" button after you have selected one or more graphics. Is there a way to trigger the delete operation through the API?

I don't see one in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no method on the Sketch widget to delete a particular or selected graphic.

One posible option is to do it manually using the updateGraphics property of the widget which is a Collection of the graphics that are being edited/selected in that moment.

With that information we can use the method removeMany() from the "graphics" property(Collection) of your GraphicsLayer to remove them.

```
...
function deleteGraphics() {
    const selectedGraphics = sketchWidget.updateGraphics; //Get selected graphics from the widget
    if (selectedGraphics) {
        graphicsLayer.graphics.removeMany(selectedGraphics); //We remove them from our layer
    }
    sketchWidget.complete(); //We "complete" the "update" event, setting updateGraphics to empty
}
...
```

If someone else has a better way to do it I will be happy if its posted, since I'm new to the ArcGIS JS API.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the graphics from layer attached to the Sketch widget : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html#layer

```
  const graphicsLayer = sketch.layer;
  graphicsLayer.removeAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, does that remove all of the graphics or only the selected graphics?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 4.14, there is now a `delete` method on the Sketch class.

`sketch.delete();`

This will delete the selected graphics associated with the Sketch instance.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html#delete